# css make layout cols left and right of main content div take up whole height of browser window

Tags: html, css, layout, height

i'm trying to make the left and right graphics of a div to take the whole height of the browser window.

At first i tried something like this https://jsfiddle.net/jr6av8n5/2/

But since the 100% height of the columns takes up the height of the parent div they do not take up the whole screen space.

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="leftLayoutCol">
    </div>
    <div id="rightLayoutCol">
    </div>
        <h1>TEST</h1>
        <h1>TEST</h1>
        <h1>TEST</h1>
        <h1>TEST</h1>
        <h1>TEST</h1>
</div>

h1 {padding:0px;margin:0px;}

#main {
    position: fixed;
    width: 55%;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin-left: 50%;
    left: -25%;
    background-color: grey;
}

#leftLayoutCol {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 40px;
    left: -40px;
    background-color: green;
}

#rightLayoutCol {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 40px;
    right: -40px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

Then i tried something like this https://jsfiddle.net/4d8d8tds/2/

This is closer to what i want to achieve but it's not a solid solution since if the browser window is resized the #main div is not horizontally centered anymore together with some other issues.

I already tried giving the body 100% height and it works except for the fact that it takes into account the height of every other page element and sums it up to the body heght making a scrollbar appear and generally looking bad (everything gets shifted down).

Any suggestions? (possibly not with css3 since it will need to run on older browsers)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The demo below shows a possible solution for it, with fixed position of `header` and `footer`, and `main` takes 100% height of the window. Due to the unpredicted height of `header` and `footer`, I added a bit of javascript to do to the calculation.

```js
var callback = function () {

    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    var headerHeight = $("#header").height();
    var footerHeight = $("#footer").height();
    var mainHeight = windowHeight - headerHeight - footerHeight;

    $("#main").css({
        "min-height": mainHeight + "px",
        "margin-top": headerHeight + "px",
        "margin-bottom": footerHeight + "px"
    });

};

$(document).ready(callback);
$(window).resize(callback);
```

```css
body, h1 {
    margin: 0;
}
#header, #footer {
    background: green;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
#header {
    top: 0;
}
#footer {
    bottom: 0;
}
#main {
    background: silver;
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#left, #right {
    background: navy;
    display: block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
#left {
    left: -40px;
}
#right {
    right: -40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="header">header</div>
<div id="main">
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>
    <h1>TEST</h1>
    <h1>TEST</h1>
    <h1>TEST</h1>
    <h1>TEST</h1>
    <h1>TEST</h1>
    <h1>TEST</h1>
    <h1>TEST</h1>
    <h1>TEST</h1>
</div>
<div id="footer">footer</div>
```

Also available on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jhdqvah6/), so you can see it in action for different window sizes.

Comment: The issue with 100% height to body and html (that is not clearly seen in the fiddle) is that i have an header and an horizontal menu under the header (let's say the total height of the header + menu is 150px) before this #main div; giving 100% height makes the page have 100% of the window's height PLUS 150px, creating a big scrollbar

Comment: @g0dl3ss It gonna be difficult, CSS3 has calc(), but you might need some JavaScript if it needs to run on old browsers. By the way, apart from the 150xpx header, is there a footer too?

Comment: There probably will be a footer but as i replied to the other answer unfortunately the header needs to be fluid since it has text in it and it needs to expand to make the text stay inside at lower resolutions. I could do it with js but i wanted to avoid it, i guess there's no css solution. Thanks for your replies

Comment: @g0dl3ss well, there is another option - using table, or css table, well that is the only way to do it without js and css3. OR if the header/footer can be fixed height, you might also be able to make them as absolute so that they will be out of the height 100%. But overall css3+js fallbacks sounds like the best option.

Comment: Thanks, i'll look into a js solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood well your question.

seems to me that if you add 100% height to both html and body in your first Fiddle it works just fine.

maybe you have seen scroll bar because by default body has margin unless set to 0.

However these days I always include in my projects, specially when working with height 100%, this:

```
* {
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
     box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

so paddings and borders will never mess up any of your elements. I recomend you to use it.

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/jr6av8n5/4/)**

Edited: if you have elements outside the 100% height container you can subtract the set height  height: calc (100% - 150px); asuming 150px is the total height of those elements combined

Comment: The issue with 100% height to body and html (that is not clearly seen in the fiddle) is that i have an header and an horizontal menu under the header (let's say the total height of the header + menu is 150px) before this #main div; giving 100% height makes the page have 100% of the window's height PLUS 150px, creating a big scrollbar

Comment: No problem. Give your lateral bars height: calc (100% - 150px); asuming 150px is the set height of both header and footer combined

Comment: Thing is that the header does not have a set height (it has some text in it and in order to make the text show inside at lower resolutions it needs to expand). I could do it with js but i'd prefer to avoid it.

Comment: Dangerous imho.I   always use set height in my headers and change it with mediaqueries if i need more room   for lower resolutions. I like to be in control of the elements with text specially considering the headaches fonts make cross brwosers. But its your web. Can't help you anymore sadly. Gl

Comment: I'll try giving a fixed height and changing it depending on the user's resolution.